Unnesting a pandas json column and keeping an "id" column
I am working on some nested NoSQL data. I would like to unnest it using json_normalize but keep the "id transação" column so I could merge the resulting dataframe into other dataframes.
import pandas as pd
import json

data = {
            "id de transação": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            "nome": ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David", "Eve"],
            "dados": [
                {"data": "2024-01-01", "local": "São Paulo", "valor": 100.50},
                {"data": "2024-01-02", "local": "Rio de Janeiro", "valor": 200.75},
                {"data": "2024-01-03", "local": "Belo Horizonte", "valor": 300.00},
                {"data": "2024-01-04", "local": "Curitiba", "valor": 400.25},
                {"data": "2024-01-05", "local": "Porto Alegre", "valor": 500.50}
            ]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

I´ve tried to use the meta parameter but did not work.
df_dados_normalized = pd.json_normalize(data = data["dados"], record_path=None, meta=data["id de transação"])


Is there a way? I would expect this resulting dataframe with the "id de transação".

meta doesn't take a Series a input, it takes a list of the keys that would constitute data to keep when passing a nested object with a record_path.
Instead, you should join the output of json_normalize to the columns to keep. Make sure to set_axis with that of df since json_normalize will create a new one:
out = (df[['id de transação', 'nome']]
       .join(pd.json_normalize(data=df['dados'], record_path=None)
               .set_axis(df.index)
            )
      )

Output:
   id de transação     nome        data           local   valor
0                1    Alice  2024-01-01       São Paulo  100.50
1                2      Bob  2024-01-02  Rio de Janeiro  200.75
2                3  Charlie  2024-01-03  Belo Horizonte  300.00
3                4    David  2024-01-04        Curitiba  400.25
4                5      Eve  2024-01-05    Porto Alegre  500.50


To give you an idea of a valid use of meta, you would need the data to be organized this way:
data = [
    {
        'id de transação': 1,
        'nome': 'Alice',
        'dados': [
            {'data': '2024-01-01', 'local': 'São Paulo', 'valor': 100.50},
        ],
    },
    {
        'id de transação': 2,
        'nome': 'Bob',
        'dados': [
            {'data': '2024-01-02', 'local': 'Rio de Janeiro', 'valor': 200.75},
            {'data': '2024-01-03', 'local': 'Belo Horizonte', 'valor': 300.00},
        ],
    },
]


out = pd.json_normalize(data=data, record_path=['dados'],
                        meta=['id de transação', 'nome'])

Output:
         data           local   valor id de transação   nome
0  2024-01-01       São Paulo  100.50               1  Alice
1  2024-01-02  Rio de Janeiro  200.75               2    Bob
2  2024-01-03  Belo Horizonte  300.00               2    Bob


Another possible solution, whose steps are:

First, the map function applies a lambda function to each element in the dados column, extracting the data, local, and valor fields and returning them as lists.

The resulting lists are converted into a dataframe using pd.DataFrame, which is then assigned to new columns date, local, and value in df.

Finally, the original dados column is removed using the drop method with the columns parameter and inplace=True to modify the dataframe directly.


df[['date', 'local', 'value']] = pd.DataFrame(
    df.dados.map(lambda x: [x['data'], x['local'], x['valor']]).tolist())

df.drop(columns=['dados'], inplace=True)

Output:
   id de transação     nome        date           local   value
0                1    Alice  2024-01-01       São Paulo  100.50
1                2      Bob  2024-01-02  Rio de Janeiro  200.75
2                3  Charlie  2024-01-03  Belo Horizonte  300.00
3                4    David  2024-01-04        Curitiba  400.25
4                5      Eve  2024-01-05    Porto Alegre  500.50


As I am running on a dask dataframe (big data), complex functions may decrease the performance too much :(
But thanks for the suggestion

Thanks for your comment, @FábioRB. Have you measured the performance of the alternative approaches? Since dask has got its own mapfunction, I would not predict a decrease in performance!
